# nandinstall on cubieboard fails:

Tags: linux

I'm unable to install onto the nand on one of my cubieboards. This is the error message:

```
cubie@Cubian:~$ sudo ~/nandinstall/install.sh                                   
This will completely destory your data on /dev/nand, Are you sure to continue? yes
spawn /home/cubie/nandinstall/sunxi-tools/nand-part /dev/nand linux 4000000 swap 8000000
check partition table copy 0: BAD!
check partition table copy 1: BAD!
check partition table copy 2: BAD!
check partition table copy 3: BAD!
all partition tables are bad!
check partition table copy 0: BAD!
check partition table copy 1: BAD!
check partition table copy 2: BAD!
check partition table copy 3: BAD!
all partition tables are bad!
send: spawn id exp6 not open
    while executing
"send "y\n""
please wait for a moment
waiting 20 seconds
waiting 10 seconds
waiting 5 seconds
mke2fs 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
Could not stat /dev/nandb --- No such file or directory

The device apparently does not exist; did you specify it correctly?
```

I've never had anything installed on the nand memory before and on my other cubieboard nandinstall worked just fine.

Comment: did you get some news on this ?  Sry I can't help, I didn't use this script. I did it from the cubian-nandinstall pckg  ( apt-get cubian-nandinstall / sudo cubian-nandinstall )

Comment: I've since reinstalled on a new sdcard, but still, cubian-nandinstall (from apt) doesn't work. It doesn't boot from NAND.

Answer (score 0):

Well, What happens when you turn on the cubieboard without the microSD?
Runs the android? or only shows a green bar?
If only shows the green bar is likely you have a problem with the partition of the nand (don't try to do a partition if it was a hdd).

Use the next command as root since the microSD

`./nand-part -f a20 /dev/nand 32768 'bootloader 20480' 'boot 512' 'rootfs 0'`

You can download nand-part from here [nand-part](http://dl.cubieforums.com/patwood/nand-part)